# Collections.emptyList() vs guava's ImmutableList.of()

Tags: java, guava

The title says it all. It is a simple question really. Just wanted to understand how both these stuffs really work.
Which would be the best option to return an immutable empty list? Would it be better to do Collections.emptyList() or ImmutableList.of() or is there a third and better option?

Comment: If your method takes an `ImmutableList` then obviously you need the Guava method. Otherwise, the Guava team themselves say, use JDK functionality in preference to Guava if available.

Comment: I always use `ImmutableList.of`. It's 5 characters shorter.

Comment: @Zheka If you use a static import, `empyList()` is admirably terse and `of()` is meaningless.

Comment: I really don't see how a third /better solution than emptyList() should look like :-)

Comment: @GhostCat `ImmutableList.of()` is easier to change to `ImmutableList.of(<args>)` if you need a list with elements instead of an empty list.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov So in order to be prepared for a change  that might come ... maybe in 1% of the cases when you wrote emptyList() ... you put up the burden of an external 3rd party library; that does much more than returning an empty list? Sounds like  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it to me

Comment: @GhostCat But if guava is already a dependency, why not use its features?

Comment: There is also java.util List.of() since Java 9, which is also an immutable list. It is much like Guava's ImmutableList.of() and that makes it super easy to migrate.

Answer (score 12):

I would use `Collections.emptyList()` because

1) why use a 3rd party library when you already have the same in JDK

2) `Collections.emptyList()` returns a real simple private class `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` (see Collections.java in JDK).

Whereas `ImmutableList.of()` returns a Guava immutable list with all the functionality as if really containing objects, initializing it with `new Object[0]`.

If you only need the empty list then you do not need the `ImmutableList` functionality.

Comment: Your third point is wrong. In Guava 21, `ImmutableList.of()` returns a singleton empty list, which is `new RegularImmutableList<Object>(ObjectArrays.EMPTY_ARRAY)`, so there's no allocation. Using the standard implementation has an advantage for the virtual method dispatch (there are many `ImmutableList` subclasses, but at most places you encounter only one or two and a mono- or bimorphic call site can be optimized better). IIRC there used to be a `EmptyImmutableList` class, but it's been dropped for efficiency reasons.